# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list'

Tags: php, laravel

I have model Article, Filegroup, File.

When save new article with image, it displays this error:

> {"exception":"Illuminate\Database\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `text`, `like_count`, `view_count`, `comment_count`, `image`, `web_image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dsvdscdscdscsdcdsc, sacsaxasxsaxsaxsaxsaxsax, 0, 0, 0, 11, 13989, 2017-06-27 15:40:49, 2017-06-27 15:40:49))","trace":[{"file":"/var/www/laravel/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php","line":726,"function":"runQueryCallback","class":"Illuminate\Database\Connection","type":"->","args":["insert into `articles` (`title`, `text`, `like_count`, `view_count`, `comment_count`, `image`, `web_image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",..................

**models/Article.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $with = ['image'];

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Filegroup', 'image_id');
    }
}
```

**models/FileGroup.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Filegroup extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'file_groups';

    protected $with = ['files', 'name'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * One-to-Many relations with SiteString.
     *
     * @foreignModel SiteString
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function name()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\SiteString', 'name_id');
    }

    /**
     * Many-to-Many relations with File.
     *
     * @foreignModel File
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\File', 'filegroup_id');
    }
}
```

**models/file.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'files';

    protected $fillable = [
        'mimi_type',
        'path',
        'width',
        'height',
        'size'
    ];

    /**
     * One-to-Many inverse relations with Filegroup.
     *
     * @foreignModel Filegroup
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Filegroup', 'filegroup_id');
    }
}
```

Tables articles created with migration:

```
class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('image_id');
            $table->text('text');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('like_count');
            $table->integer('view_count');
            $table->integer('comment_count');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('articles');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please verify if column `image` exists in table `articles`

Comment: `image` and `web_image` does not exists in your articles migration

Comment: image column does not exist in your articles table migration

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `$guarded` attributes on a model rather than `$fillable` it will try and insert every value in the attributes array of your model. More on that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

You can either make sure that the array of attributes that you're assigning to your article model only contains attributes that have corresponding database columns or you can switch to `$fillable` like so:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'image_id',
    'text',
    'title',
    'like_count',
    'view_count',
    'comment_count',
];
```